# Matching balanced and nested braces in input text

Tags: c++, algorithm

I attended a quiz, I gave the code but the auto-test shows that one of the eight test cases failed. 
I myself tested my code many times, but all passed. I can't find where is the problem.

The question is to design a algorithm to check whether the brackets in a string match.

1) Just consider rounded brackets `()` and square brackets `[]`, omit ohter chars.
2) Each pair brackets should match each other. That means `（` matches `)`, and `[` matches `]`.
3) Intercrossing is not allowed, such as : `([)]`. There are two pairs of brackets, but they intercross each other.

To solve the problem, my method is described as follows:

1. Search each char in the whole input string, the index from 0 to str.size() - 1.
2. Use two stacks to record the opening tag `(`, and `[`, each type in one stack. When encountering one of them, push its index in the corresponding stack.
3. When encouterning the closing tag `)` and `]`, we pop the corresponding stack.
4. Before popping, check the top of two stacks, the current stack should have the max index, otherwise that means there are unmatched opening tag with the other type, so the intercrossing can be checked this way.

My Code is Here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;

    stack<int> s1, s2;
    int result = 0;
    for (int ix = 0, len = str.size(); ix < len; ix++)
    {
        if (str[ix] == '(')
        {
            s1.push(ix);
        }
        else if (str[ix] == '[')
        {
            s2.push(ix);
        }
        else if (str[ix] == ')')
        {
            if (s1.empty() || (!s2.empty() && s1.top() < s2.top()))
            {
                result = 1;
                break;
            }
            s1.pop();
        }
        else if (str[ix] == ']')
        {
            if (s2.empty() || (!s1.empty() && s2.top() < s1.top()))
            {
                result = 1;
                break;
            }
            s2.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
    if (!s1.empty() || !s2.empty())
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

As methoned before, this question can be solved by just on stack, so I modified my code, and here is the single stack version. [THE KEY POINT IS NOT TO ARGUE WHITCH IS BETTER, BUT WHAT'S WRONG WITH MY CODE.]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;

    stack<char> s;
    const char *p = str.c_str();
    int result = 0;
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        if (*p == '(' || *p == '[')
        {
            s.push(*p);
        }
        else if (*p == ')')
        {
            if (s.empty() || s.top() != '(')
            {
                result = 1;
                break;
            }
            s.pop();
        }
        else if (*p == ']')
        {
            if (s.empty() || s.top() != '[')
            {
                result = 1;
                break;
            }
            s.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        p++;
    }
    if (!s.empty())
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

Comment: Without looking at the algorithm: first, you **always** need to check that your input was successful. Next, your code will fail with the input `( )`: although the parenthesis match, you won't even see the second parenthesis.

Comment: @bengoesboom Why's that?

Comment: @DietmarKühl I think that's the answer.

Comment: Your title is not descriptive. _Bad_ way to name a question.

Comment: @jrok oh nevermind, I thought the character was being pushed, not the index :)

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl I see, if the input contains "space", the statement "cin >> string" will read just part of the input string.
Is there other problem besides this?

Comment: @bengoesboom yep that caught me too.

Comment: What was the failed test-case?  That would help narrow down why your code failed.

Comment: @Violet Giraffe Sure, I'm not native in english. In fact, there are no problem with the logic and coding. Everything seems OK. That is too painful. Better TITLE is welcomed!

Comment: @user1842790: I think the algorithm is more complicated than necessary but I think it should work. It seems a space in the input is the most likely source of the failure: I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: @pjs That's the point. Because that is a test for job application, I don't know the test case.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl Thank you! If IO is the only problem, there is no need to do any changes. That is a test, which has passed yet.

Comment: the solution with two stacks looks better. And should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using formatted input to read a `std::string` only the first word is read: after skipping leading whitespate a string is read until the first whitespace is encountered. As a result, the input `( )` should match but `std::cin >> str` would only read `(`. Thus, the input should probably look like this:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin, str)) {
    // algorithm for matching parenthesis and brackets goes here
}
```

Using `std::getline()` still makes an assumption about how the input is presented, namely that it is on one line. If the algorithm should process the entire input from `std::cin` I would use

```
str.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin),
           std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Although I think the algorithm is unnecessary complex (on stack storing the kind of parenthesis would suffice), I also *think* that it should work, i.e., the only problem I spotted is the way the input is obtained.

Comment: Good, I can understand that! std::getline() assumes the terminator is '\n', while the iterator method assumes the terminator is EOF! I'm not familiar whit IO in c++, and IO was not required in this test before, so I donnot think in this aspect.

Comment: If there has no logical or coding problem, I will choose this post as the ANSWER.